# Get the current time in jPlayer

Tags: php, jplayer

I want to get the current time of a song, for which I am using

```
var currentTime = $('#jquery_jplayer_1').data("jPlayer").status.currentTime;
```

but I am getting and error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined** in the console.

What i am trying to do is suppose a song is playing and when the user clicks on the playbutton of another song i want to get the time played of the previous song and then start playing the clicked song.

Here is my code:

```
var currentTime = $('#jquery_jplayer_1').data("jPlayer").status.currentTime;
alert(currentTime);

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("stop");

var id = "#jquery_jplayer_1";
var media = {
    mp3: audio_element
};
var options = {
    swfPath: "/appystream/assets/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window"
};
var currentTime = $('#jquery_jplayer_1').data("jPlayer").status.currentTime;
alert(currentTime);

// jPlayer android versions 2.3 fix.
var myFix = new jPlayerAndroidFix(id, media, options);
myFix.setMedia(media).play();
setTimeout(function () {
    myFix.setMedia(media).play();
}, 2000);
```

No matter where I put the code  to get the current time, it responds with the error given above..

What am I doing wrong ? how else can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing things in the wrong way. I way I did the things is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jp").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4v: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270_h264aac.m4v",
                ogv: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/ogv/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.ogv",
                poster: "http://www.jplayer.org/video/poster/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer_480x270.png"
            });
        },
        ended: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "m4v, ogv"
    });

    $("#jp").bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, function(event) { 
        var currentTime = Math.floor(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime)

        if (currentTime < 3){
            $("#slideshow").html("<img src='http://yoursite.com.com/wm/jplayer/slides/slide1.png'/>");  
        }

        if (currentTime >= 3 && currentTime < 12){
            $("#slideshow").html("<img src='http://yoursite.com.com/wm/jplayer/slides/slide2.png'/>");  
        }

        if (currentTime >= 12 && currentTime < 16){
            $("#slideshow").html("<img src='http://yoursite.com.com/wm/jplayer/slides/slide3.png'/>");  
        }

        if (currentTime >= 16 && currentTime < 22){
            $("#slideshow").html("<img src='http://yoursite.com.com/wm/jplayer/slides/slide4.png'/>");  
        }

        if (currentTime >= 22 && currentTime < 30){
            $("#slideshow").html("<img src='http://yoursite.com.com/wm/jplayer/slides/slide5.png'/>");  
        }


        if (currentTime >= 30){
            $("#slideshow").html("<img src='http://yoursite.com.com/wm/jplayer/slides/fin.png'/>"); 
        }



    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply dude.. Although this was not the answer I was expecting, I got an idea out of it :)

Answer (score 1):

I know did is an old question, but I just needed the same answer as you were hopefully expecting and found the solution.

This is probably the thing you wanted?

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer()[0].childNodes[1].currentTime
```

If not, play around in $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer()[0].childNodes to find audio element. But as far as I know there should be only two elements there - img and audio. Audio is the second one, that's why you do childNodes[1].

Hope this helps